# Validation form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, validation, messagebox, is-empty

Stupid question!

I'm checking if the inputboxes are empty...but after the check, I want to navigate back to my form and give the user a second chance to change their input.

At this moment, the app will show a messagebox if it's empty, but he goes further in my code to the second check...is there a code where I can break the code an go back to the form?

My code:

```
    If naam = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Naam mag niet leeg zijn", "No entry",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If


    prijsstr = TextBox2.Text
    If prijsstr = "" Then
        MsgBox("Prijs mag niet leeg zijn")
    ElseIf IsNumeric(prijsstr) = False Then
        MsgBox("Prijs moet numeriek zijn")
    Else
        prijs = Integer.Parse(prijsstr)
    End If

    If prijs < 0 Then
        MsgBox("Prijs mag niet onder 0 zijn")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just `Return`?

```
If naam = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Naam mag niet leeg zijn", "No entry",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return
End If


prijsstr = TextBox2.Text
If prijsstr = "" Then
    MsgBox("Prijs mag niet leeg zijn")
    Return
ElseIf IsNumeric(prijsstr) = False Then
    MsgBox("Prijs moet numeriek zijn")
    Return
Else
    prijs = Integer.Parse(prijsstr)
End If

If prijs < 0 Then
    MsgBox("Prijs mag niet onder 0 zijn")
    Return
End If
```